# Call an exe (7z) with a foreach in Powershell

Tags: powershell, foreach, exe, 7zip

I'm struggling getting powershell to find .zip files that are encrypted and extract 1 file from them. Any help would be appreciated and thank you in advance.

In Powershell this works when the path is hard-coded after the 'e':

```
$exe = 'C:\Temp\7z.exe'
$ZipPath = 'C:\Temp'
& $exe -pPASSWORD -o"$ZipPath" e "$ZipPath\23.02.2021.22.00.01.bak.zip" web.config -r
```

However I would like it to find the .zip and then extract a web.config file from it. I use write-host to output the file visually so I can see it is the correct file, which it finds as:

> Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\Temp\23.02.2021.22.00.01.bak.zip

but I get the error:

> ERROR: The system cannot find the file specified.
> Microsoft.PowerShell.Core
> System ERROR:
> The system cannot find the
> file specified.

I have tried the below with no luck:

```
$exe = 'C:\Temp\7z.exe'
$ZipPath = 'C:\Temp'
$ZipFile = Get-ChildItem $ZipPath *.zip -rec

foreach ($file in $ZipFile)
{
    Write-Host 'file:' $file.PSPath
    & $exe -pPASSWORD -o"$ZipPath" e $file.PSPath web.config -r
}
```

I also tried:

```
$exe = 'C:\Temp\7z.exe'
$ZipPath = 'C:\Temp'
$ZipFile = Get-ChildItem $ZipPath *.zip -rec

foreach ($file in $ZipFile)
{
    Write-Host 'file:' $file.PSPath
    & $exe -argumentList "-pPASSWORD", "-o$ZipPath", "e", "$file.PSPath", "web.config", "-r" -wait
}
```

This is the full output of running my first FOREACH, without the Argument list switch:

> file: Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\Temp\23.02.2021.22.00.01.bak.zip
>
> 7-Zip 18.05 (x64) : Copyright (c) 1999-2018 Igor Pavlov : 2018-04-30
>
> Scanning the drive for archives: 7z.exe :  At line:10 char:5
> `+`     & $exe -pPASSWORD -o$ZipPath e $file.PSPath web.config -r
> `+`     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>     `+` CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:String) [], RemoteException
>     `+` FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
>
> ERROR: The system cannot find the file specified.
> Microsoft.PowerShell.Core
> System ERROR:
> The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: Take a look at options here: [PowerShell: Running Executables](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7703.powershell-running-executables.aspx) As for the loop, how about just doign this: `(Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\temp\*.zip' -Recurse).FullName | ForEach{...}`?

Answer (score 0):

I solved a minimal example - just extract all zip files to a directory of the same name - since I don't have zip files set up like yours. What I'm hoping here is that you can use the format of what I've created to solve the parameter embedding issue in your question.

```
Get-ChildItem *.zip | ForEach-Object {
    # no -argumentList, just pass the parameters like you'd enter them
    # (just with variables where you need them)
    & "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" x $($_.FullName) -o*
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> ERROR: The system cannot find the file specified.
> Microsoft.PowerShell.Core

This suggests that you're passing a `PSPath` property as the command-line argument to 7-Zip. It is likely seeing:

```
Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\Temp\23.02.2021.22.00.01.bak.zip
```

Which isn't a valid path outside PowerShell. To avoid this in future, you can use the `FullName` property of the [`[FileInfo]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo) objects returned by [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem). Also, `-ArgumentList` and `-Wait` are parameters of [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) and will not work with the [call operator `&`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators#call-operator-).

As you are expecting there to be multiple archives and therefore multiple `web.config` files, a better approach may be to use the include archive [`-ai`](https://documentation.help/7-Zip/ar_include.htm) switch of 7-Zip to search for archives in a directory. You would also want to use [`-an`](https://documentation.help/7-Zip/ar_no.htm) to disable the *archive_name* field, and [`-aou`](https://documentation.help/7-Zip/overwrite.htm) in order to auto-rename each *web.config* extracted since you're using the [extract `e`](https://documentation.help/7-Zip/extract1.htm) command which extracts all to one directory.

```
$exe = 'C:\Temp\7z.exe'
$ZipPath = 'C:\Temp'
$InnerFilename = 'web.config'
$Password = 'PASSWORD'

$7zParams = @{
    FilePath = $exe
    ArgumentList = 'e -an -aou -r -p"{0}" -o"{1}" -air!"{2}" "{3}"' -f
        $Password, $ZipPath, "$ZipPath\*.zip", $InnerFilename
    Wait = $true
}
Start-Process @7zParams
```

A quick run-down of the 7-Zip switches used here in order, for anyone else interested:

| Parameter | Description |
| --- | --- |
| `e` | Extract files without directory structure |
| `-an` | Disable *archive_name* processing |
| `-aou` | Do not overwrite files with same name, auto-rename extracted files |
| `-r` | Search inside each archive recursively |
| `-p"<password>"` | Use `<password>` to decrypt archives |
| `-o"<path>"` | Extract files to `<path>` |
| `-air!"<path>\*.zip"` | Search recursively in `<path>` for ZIP archives |
| `<filename>` | Search for files matching `<filename>` in each archive |